# create an DNS MX Record

Tags: email, dns

I'm traying to create an MX record using GCP CloudDNS. I created a A record pointing to my server IP. And I wanted to creat an MX record as following:
A mail.mydomain.fake 
MX @mydomain.fake mail.mydomain.fake

While creating the MX record I get the following error:

Invalid value for `entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[0]`

Below some screen shots:
A record:
[image: A record]

The MX Record:

[image: MX Record]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I miss adding priority! just put a leading number and worked.

I'm new on DNS thingy that's why I'm doing it.